# IsAjaxRequest is always false after upgrade to RC MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I updated the AJAX scripts and assembly referenced as per release notes. However, IsAjaxRequest still always returns false despite it actually being such a request. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Zsharp, were you successful? I'm having the exact same problem you had before. Please help!

Comment: i got it to work but i cant remember offhand what was wrong. did you change scripts or are you using the latest version of mvc?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you are using MS Ajax library. You should update your MicrosoftMvcAjax.js too. It was changed.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have a problem using RC1 Updated ...
As a test I added this action to the Home Controller

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    ifRequest.IsAjaxRequest())
        return PartialView();
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

and this to the Home/Index.aspx file

Test Target

Created Views/Home/Test.ascx

```
</br>This is a test
```

and added the Ajax Javascript Files to the Master Page

---

In response to comments I added an AjaxForm to the Index.aspx and it worked

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="indexHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <title>Home Page</title>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="indexContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2><%= Html.Encode(ViewData["Message"]) %></h2>
    <p>
        To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
    </p>

    <%= Ajax.ActionLink("Test", "Test", new AjaxOptions{ UpdateTargetId="TestTarget", InsertionMode=InsertionMode.InsertAfter} ) %>
    <div id="TestTarget">Test Target</div>

    <% using(Ajax.BeginForm("Test", new AjaxOptions{ UpdateTargetId="TestTarget", InsertionMode=InsertionMode.InsertAfter} ) ){%>

    <button type="submit" >click me</button>

    <% } %>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: i didnt try with actionlink, but it didnt work with ajax form.